# ¿Por qué los datos del vector no se ordenan?

Tags: c++, ordenamiento

Tengo problemas para ordenar alfabéticamente por nombres esta estructura, el código es el siguiente

```
struct Fecha
{
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int anio;
}f[lenght];

struct persona{
    string nombre;
    string apellido;
    char sexo;
    struct Fecha nacimiento;
}p[lenght];


 //Este es mi metodo para ordenar las personas (estoy utilizando el metodo burbuja, pero no me quiere ordenar la estructura)
void ordenarpersona(persona *p){
    persona temp;
    
    for(int i = 0 ; i < lenght; i++){
        
        for(int j = 0; j < lenght; j++){
            
            if(p[i].nombre> p[j].nombre){
                temp = p[i];
                p[i]= p[j];
                p[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }   
            
}
```

Después de que utilizo el método de ordenar, imprimo nuevamente (con un método aparte), pero no me salen las estructuras ordenadas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema radica en este bloque de código:

```
if(p[i].nombre> p[j].nombre)
{
     temp = p[i];
     p[i]= p[j];
     p[j] = temp;
}
```

Como verás, estás comparando el primer nombre con el primero, luego con el segundo y así sucesivamente, sin embargo, así no es el algoritmo de la burbuja.

**El método burbuja funciona así:**

Si el elemento anterior es mayor al elemento siguiente, hacemos el intercambio.

En código quedaría así:

```
//ordena los nombres alfabéticamente..
void ordenarpersona(persona *p)
{
    persona temp;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < lenght; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j < lenght; j++)
        {
            if(p[j - 1].nombre > p[j].nombre)
            {
                temp = p[j];
                p[j]= p[j - 1];
                p[j - 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Podemos evitar hacer comparaciones innecesarias cuando el arreglo esté ordenado.

Método burbuja mejorado *versión 2*:

```c
void ordenarpersona(persona *p)
{
    bool cambio = true;
    persona temp;
   //Mientras haya al menos un intercambio de datos..
    while(cambio)
    {
        cambio = false;
        for(int j = 1; j < lenght; j++)
        {
            if(p[j - 1].nombre > p[j].nombre)
            {
                temp = p[j];
                p[j]= p[j - 1];
                p[j - 1] = temp;
                cambio = true;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Si analizamos el algoritmo, podemos deducir que cada vez que se ejecute el bucle for anidado, mandará al final del arreglo el elemento mayor.

Por ejemplo, si tenemos esta sucesión:

```c
2,8,3,4,1
```

El bucle anidado posicionará el elemento mayor al final y esto se repite una y otra vez:

```c
2,8,3,4,1
2,3,8,4,1
2,3,4,8,1
2,3,4,1,8
```

Entonces, con esto podemos comprobar que no necesitamos recorrer todo el arreglo de nuevo, sino, simplemente debemos ir hasta el elemento que esté antes del mayor (en nuestro ejemplo anterior, el número `1` es el elemento que está antes del número `8`).

De este modo, podemos tener un método burbuja mejorado *versión 3*:

```c
void ordenarpersona(persona *p)
{
    bool cambio = true;
    int len = lenght;
    persona temp;
    while(cambio)
    {
        cambio = false;
        for(int j = 1; j < len; j++)
        {
            if(p[j - 1].nombre > p[j].nombre)
            {
                temp = p[j];
                p[j]= p[j - 1];
                p[j - 1] = temp;
                cambio = true;
            }
        }
        --len;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias bro, me ha ayudado bastante

Comment: Entiendo, gracias, soy nuevo en Stackoverflow asi que no lo sabia @Trauma