# PROGRAMA C++, USO DE MÉTODO DE ORDENACIÓN (Selección, Inserción, Burbuja, Shell, QuickSort)

Tags: c++

Necesito ayuda para elaborar un programa en C++ que permita capturar y guardar la temperatura promedio que se tuvo cada día de la semana, posteriormente, utilizando cualquier método de ordenación, desplegar todas las temperaturas en forma ascendente y descendente. También indicar cuál fue el día más caluroso y el más frío. Agradecería si me pudieran dar ideas, sugerencias, o alguna iteración de ejemplo.

**Como debería mostrarse en archivo ejecutable**

```
Capture la temperatura promedio del día LUNES: 17.3
Capture la temperatura promedio del día MARTES: 24.0
Capture la temperatura promedio del día MIÉRCOLES: 16.5
Capture la temperatura promedio del día JUEVES: 18.0
Capture la temperatura promedio del día VIERNES: 11.0
Capture la temperatura promedio del día SABADO: 17.5
Capture la temperatura promedio del día DOMINGO: 23.0
Los valores ordenados de forma ascendente son:    
 11.0, 16.5,  17.3,  17.5,  18.0,  23.0,  24.0
Los valores ordenados de forma descendente son:   
24.0,  23.0,  18.0,  17.5,  17.3,  16.5,  11.0
El día más caluroso fue el MARTES
El día más frío fue el VIERNES
```

**CÓDIGO**

```
  #include <iostream>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <stdio.h> 
    #include <stdlib.h> 
    
    using namespace std;
    
    struct materia{
        char lunes[30];
        char martes[30];
        char miercoles[30];
        char jueves[30];
        char viernes[10];
    };
    int main()
    {
        struct materia mat[1];  
        
        for(int i=0;i<1;i++)
        {
           cout<<"Capture la temperatura promedio del dia LUNES: ";
           cin>>mat[i].lunes;
           cout<<"Capture la temperatura promedio del dia MARTES: ";
           cin>>mat[i].martes;
           cout<<"Capture la temperatura promedio del dia MIERCOLES: ";
           cin>>mat[i].miercoles;
           cout<<"Capture la temperatura promedio del dia JUEVES: "; 
           cin>>mat[i].jueves;
           cout<<"Capture la temperatura promedio del dia VIERNES: ";
           cin>>mat[i].viernes;
           cout<<endl;
        }
    cout<<"Los valores ordenados de forma ascendente: ";
        for(int i=0;i<99.99;i++){
            cout<<mat[i].lunes<<mat[i].martes<<mat[i].miercoles<<mat[i].jueves<<mat[i].viernes<<" ";
        }
        
        cout<<"\nLos valores ordenados de forma descendente: ";
        for(int i=0;i<2;i--){
            cout<<mat[i].lunes<<mat[i].martes<<mat[i].miercoles<<mat[i].jueves<<mat[i].viernes<<" ";
        }
    
    cout<<"Los día más caluroso fue: \n"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
           cout<<mat[i].lunes<<"\t"<<mat[i].martes<<"\t"<<mat[i].miercoles<<"\t"<<mat[i].jueves<<"\t"<<"\t"<<mat[i].viernes<<"\n";
        }
    system("pause");
    }
```

GRACIAS POR SU ATENCIÓN, APRECIARÍA ENORMEMENTE SU AYUDA Y ASESORÍA EN ESTA DUDA.
SALUDOS.

Comment: Mira este [hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/365295/por-qu%c3%a9-los-datos-del-vector-no-se-ordenan/365302#365302)..

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Disculpen por omitir lo que llevaba, no soy muy bueno con C++, pero si pudieran darme ejemplos o algún material que me pudiera ayudar también se los agradecería, disculpen la anterior pregunta.