# Formar ascendente de un vector

Tags: c

tengo un pequeño error con el método de la burbuja que no está ordenando de formar correcta los números, de forma mayor a menor no tengo problema pero de menor a mayor sí.

Ya revise los for y no veo el error, gracias.

```
int FomraDes(int mat[], int a)
{
    int i,j,d;
    a = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <(a-1); ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0 ; j < (a-i-1); ++j)
        {
            if (mat[d] > mat[d+1])
            {
                a=mat[d];
                mat[d]=mat[d+1];
                mat[d+1] = a;
            }
        }
    }
}

int EscribirMat (int mat[], int a)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < a; ++i)
    {
        printf("%i", mat[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira en tu función FomraDes tienes declarada una variable d que no hace nada. Prueba a trazar paso a paso para ver cómo varia el valor de d y verás que hay un fallo de los gordos.

Comment: Oye, además en la función FomraDes pones a=0 haces cero el parámetro pasado (se supone que es el número de elementos) que al ponerlo a cero lo que hace es que ni siquiera entra en el bucle. Y si no lo pones a cero, luego pecas al usarlo como variable temporal para intercambiar e l valor de dos elementos en el array.

Comment: Lo que debes intercambiar son los elementos de la posición `j-1` y `j`. Por ende, la condición quedaría así: `mat[j - 1] > mat[j]`. Claro la variable `j` debe empezar en `1` y terminar en el valor que tenga guardado `a` (que es el número máximo de elementos del *array*). Este [hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/365295/por-qu%c3%a9-los-datos-del-vector-no-se-ordenan/365302#365302) te ayudará a resolver tu problema.

Comment: Considera refactorizar los nombres de tus funciones a otros más explicativos y completos. Por ejemplo, de `EscribirMat` a `escribirMatriz`, y de `FomraDesc` a `odenarDescendente`. Y recuerda seguir las convenciones de nombrado de variables y funciones en C (empezar identificadores por minúscula).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código tiene ciertos problemas en la lógica del ordenamiento, adjunto la corrección al mismo.

```
 int FomraDes(int mat[], int a)
{
    int i,j;
    a=0;
    for (i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<a;j++)
        {
            //numero actual menor a numero siguiente para imprimir de forma des
            if (mat[j] < mat[j+1])
            {
                //algoritmo de ordenamiento para mover el numero actual
                a=mat[j];
                mat[j]=mat[j+1];
                mat[j+1]=a;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

El método de ordenamiento "burbujeo optimizado" que estas utilizando consta de verificar si numero actual (mat[j]) es menor a numero siguiente (mat[j+1]), si eso mismo se cumple se necesita un intercambio de los valores realizado de la siguiente manera.

```
 auxiliar=mat[numeroactual(j)]
 mat[numeroactual(j)]=mat[numerosiguiente(j+1)]
 mat[numerosiguiente(j+1)]=auxiliar;
```

Espero haber contestado tu pregunta.
Suerte!

Comment: 1. La condición de salida del bucle anidado debería ser: `j < a - 1`, de lo contrario, habrá un desbordamiento de búfer cuando `j` tome el último índice. 2. La variable **a** no la puedes tomar como auxiliar, porque ahí es donde tienes guardado el tamaño del *array*, se debería declarar otra variable aparte.

Comment: No puede poner a=0. Ya que hace que no entre siquiera en el bucle.

Comment: a=0 es la forma de inicial izar la variable, en caso de que se quiera realizar el bucle el programa debería de agregar algo mas de información, únicamente mostré el método de ordenamiento.